# Why is my ng-repeat is only displaying first result?

Tags: angularjs

I have this array of an array of objects that I am pushing onto from results I pass from a modal;

```
[
  [
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "THROTTLE TUBE",
  "partno": "104-",
  "oemnumber": "46019 038",
  "stock": 19,
  "price": "28"
},
{
  "id": 28,
  "name": "TACHOMETER, CUP",
  "partno": "128-",
  "oemnumber": "25012 011",
  "stock": 7,
  "price": "46"
}
  ]
]
```

I am getting this from the following;

```
 $scope.woParts = [];

//later in my modal code - which is where the double [] is coming from
modalInstance.result.then(function(woParts) {
        $scope.woParts.push(woParts);
```

I am then using this ng-repeat in my view;

```
<div ng-repeat="woPart in woParts">
   <div class="col-md-4">
      @{{ woPart[$index].name }}
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      @{{ woPart[$index].oemnumber }}
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      @{{ woPart[$index].price | currency}}
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="number" 
             class="form-control"
             ng-model="partQty">
   </div>
 </div>
```

This only displays the first result in the array.  Why is that?
Thanks!

Comment: can i ask why you put double [] in the json , if there is one  i think it wii work fine

Comment: Good question.  Check my edit...

Comment: try to use {{ woPart.name }}  

"woPart" which i understand refer to object in the array not using index

Comment: If I remove [$index] from the repeat I get no results at all.

Comment: I don't think you should push woParts into another object. Just save it to the scope: `$scope.woParts = woParts;`. Then there is no need to use `$index` in the ngRepeat, just use regular dot notation: `woPart.name`.

Comment: Or if you have to push woParts into another array, then you can change the ngRepeat expression to `woPart in woParts[0]`

Comment: OzW That's it.  I am sure I tried that initially with no luck.  Anyway, works now.  Can you post that as an answer and I'll approve?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should push woParts into another object. Just save it to the scope: `$scope.woParts = woParts;`. Then there is no need to use `$index` in the ngRepeat, just use regular dot notation: `woPart.name`.

Or if you have to push woParts into another array, then you can change the ngRepeat expression to `woPart in woParts[0]`.